# How do I create a file that is modified if any duplicates are found

Tags: c++, file, winapi, directory

I want a file to be created by the name given by a user. If the file name already exists I want the file name to be automatically modified before the creation.

```
if (GetFileAttributesA((name).c_str()) != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
{
    int num = 0;
    //If True: Modify File Name
    while (GetFileAttributesA((name + "" + to_string(num) + "").c_str()) != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
    {
        cout << (GetFileAttributesA((name + "" + to_string(num) + "").c_str()) != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) << endl;
        num++;
    }
    CreateFileA((name + "" + to_string(num) + "" + ".txt").c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, NULL, NULL);
    cout << "Created new file at: ";
    cout << (name + "" + to_string(num) + "" + ".txt").c_str() << endl;
}
else
{
    CreateFileA(name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, NULL, NULL);
    cout << "Created new file at: ";
    cout << (name + ".txt").c_str() << endl;
}
```

1st Run Program

`Created new file at: Created new file at: D:\Users\Me\HD-Visual Studio Repos\Visual Studio Repo\McFG\Text Generator Function Generator\Generated txt\base.txt`

2nd Run Program

`Created new file at: Created new file at: D:\Users\Me\HD-Visual Studio Repos\Visual Studio Repo\McFG\Text Generator Function Generator\Generated txt\base1.txt`

3rd Run Program

`Created new file at: Created new file at: D:\Users\Me\HD-Visual Studio Repos\Visual Studio Repo\McFG\Text Generator Function Generator\Generated txt\base1.txt`

By the third time it starts to create duplicates again.

`name = D:\Users\Me\HD-Visual Studio Repos\Visual Studio Repo\McFG\Text Generator Function Generator\Generated txt\base`

Comment: The file you are checking for, with `GetFileAttributes` is not the same as the file you are creating. Note where you are putting in the `num`

Comment: typical problem coming when a code is complicated for nothing,  computing several times the same thing (in fact *almost* the same thing because of the bug) ...

Comment: @ChrisMM So I am trying to create a file that is tested to see if that file already exists. If the file already exists then the name of the file I am trying to create is then modified by adding a number to the end of it. If the modified file already exists, then the number will be changed and tested again.

Comment: @JaedonKLB we all understand that, but **you** do you understand his remark ?

Comment: @JaedonKLB don't use `GetFileAttributes` at all, that introduces a race condition. `CreateFile` has flags to fail if a file exists. Call `CreateFile` in a loop, creating a new filename on each iteration, until creation is successful

Comment: @bruno not if the loop handles the errors properly. `GetLastError` will tell him why `CreateFile` fails. In this case, loop while `CreateFile` fails with `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` only, anything else is a fatal error that should break the loop

Comment: Consider debugging your program.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you concatenating all those zero-length strings?

Answer (score 2):

Using `GetFileAttributes()` the way you are introduces a race condition. Another process could create/delete the file after you check for its existence and before you can open/create it.  `CreateFile()` has flags to make it fail if a file already exists, you should be using that feature instead.  In your example, setting the `dwCreationDisposition` parameter to 2 (`CREATE_ALWAYS`) overwrites an existing file.  Set the parameter to 1 (`CREATE_NEW`) instead.  Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea):

> CREATE_ALWAYS
>   2
>
> Creates a new file, always.
>
> If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites the file, the function succeeds, and last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
>
> If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path, a new file is created, the function succeeds, and the last-error code is set to zero.
>
> ...
>
> CREATE_NEW
>   1
>
> Creates a new file, only if it does not already exist.
>
> If the specified file exists, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_EXISTS (80).
>
> If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, a new file is created.

For example:

```cpp
string filename = name + ".txt";
int num = 0;
HANDLE hFile;

do
{
    hFile = CreateFileA(filename.c_str(), 0, 0, NULL, CREATE_NEW, 0, NULL);
    if ((hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_EXISTS))
        filename = name + to_string(num++) + ".txt";
    else
        break;
}
while (true);

if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    cout << "Created new file at: " << filename << endl;
    // use hFile as needed...
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
else
{
    DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
    cerr << "Unable to create new file at: " << filename << ". Error " << errCode << endl;
    // error handling...
}
```